# Как сделать так чтобы программа не завершала скрипт?

Tags: python

У меня есть программа которая по моей формуле вычесляет мне нужные значения, но после того как я вписал и мне выдало результат, приходиться перезапускать прогу. Как сделать так чтобы прогу не нужно было перезапускать после каждого использования?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB